# Android realm migration error

Tags: android, realm, realm-migration

In my project, you need to configure the migration of realm. I created a migration class, but if a RealmMigrationNeededException occurs, then the database should be recreate.
My code

```
RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
            .schemaVersion(3)
            .migration(new Migration())
            .build();
boolean exceptionIsThrow = false;
try {
    Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(realmConfiguration);
    realm.close();
} catch (RealmMigrationNeededException e) {
    Realm.deleteRealm(realmConfiguration);
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                  .schemaVersion(3)
                  .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
                  .build());
    exceptionIsThrow = true;
}
```

The application falls on the line `Realm.deleteRealm(realmConfiguration);`

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: It's not allowed to delete the file associated with an open Realm. Remember to close() all the instances of the Realm before deleting its file

How can I correctly migrate?

Comment: if the try fails in the first line, realm.close() won't be called

Comment: Also make sure you use a newer version of Realm, specifically 4.3.0 or newer

Comment: I use realm version 4.1.0

Comment: "if the try fails in the first line, realm.close() won't be called"
Yes. How can I resolve this situation?

Comment: How can I close an instance of realm if it was called RealmMigrationNeededException

Comment: By calling `realm.close` in the catch block too

Comment: The error was corrected by updating realm to version 5.0.0. Thank